# How to execute shell command after compile finished from .pro in QT?

Tags: qt, qmake

What changes must I make to the `.pro` file if I want to execute `chmod` command, execute the output binary file, or do some other operations.

Comment: Could that be done via QMAKE_POST_LINK? Never used this myself, so I won't put it as an answer. Perhaps worth a look?

Comment: I have tried  QMAKE_POST_LINK,it works well!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I wanted a special tool (versioner) to run over the code every time the Makefile was executed. Here's the solution:

(to be read in the [Qmake Manual, Configuring qmake's Environment, Section: Customizing Makefile Output](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html#customizing-makefile-output))

Create you own Makefile target. Specify the command etc.

```
mytarget.target = .buildfile
mytarget.commands = touch $$mytarget.target

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mytarget
```

This way, you have an extra target you can call with `make mytarget` for example. If you want to tie it together to the actual buildtarget you'll have to add:

```
POST_TARGETDEPS += mytarget
```

Hope that helps.

Best regards
D

Comment: in this case, touch command will execute after compile finished and before link, if want to execute touch after link, QMAKE_POST_LINK is suitable.

Comment: Don't you also want `mytarget.depends = FORCE`?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make things in given order is to use empty "super" target:

```
super.depends = target_pre first target_post
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += super
```

Where `first` - is default qmake target, and `target_pre` and `target_post` some custom targets. Now `make super` just do the thing.

**EDIT**: looks like in last versions of Qt build of dependencies is running in paralell so this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Qt Creator, you can add custom build steps in the Projects panel: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.1/creator-build-settings.html#adding-custom-build-steps

Comment: Bad answer.  Never mess with .pro.user settings when you can achieve a goal via QMake.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer depends on exactly what you want, and when.  However, as seen in some previously posted comments here `QMAKE_POST_LINK` is probably what you want rather than `POST_TARGETDEPS`.

Check out this related post:
[QMake: execute script after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528022/qmake-execute-script-after-build)

For one, when you use `POST_TARGETDEPS` that fires off BEFORE your exe is created (in Windows) or BEFORE it is recreated (in Linux)!  QMake works differently depending upon the platform and the complier.

I needed to do some "symbols processing" on an exe when it was recompiled.  `POST_TARGETDEPS` gave me problems in both Windows (using mingw) and Linux (using gcc).  In Windows, it executed my script prematurely, and in Linux it overwrote my exe after I had modified it (i.e. added back my debugging info to the exe after I had stripped it in my external script).  `QMAKE_POST_LINK` worked perfectly, however, in both cases.  It's also short, sweet, and more clear by comparison!