# Get qmake to execute shell script after build finished on Mac

Tags: qt, qmake, post-build-event

After my release build is finished I would like to run a script.

I found this question [How to execute shell command after compile finished from .pro in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5946896/791821) but the answer doesn't work for me.  I tried adding various modifications of this to my .pro file:

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    mytarget.target = ./MyScript.sh
    mytarget.commands = touch $$mytarget.target

    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS +=mytarget
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += mytarget
}
```

But this always results with ":-1: error: mytarget: No such file or directory".  Path is correct and 'MyScript.sh' works fine from command line.

Since this works for other people I guess I’m doing something wrong.  I use Qt 4.7.2 on Mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Path is relative to build directory. If your script is not in your build directory,you have to change path. 
Try using ../MyScript.sh

Why are you using target? If your only intent is to execute MyScript.sh after the build, you need only

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += ./MyScript.sh
```

Comment: I'll try it (can't right now) but I don't think that's the issue.  “MyScript.sh” sits on the same level as my Forms directory, which contains a few header files used elsewhere.  Since "INCLUDEPATH += ./Forms" seems to be doing its job I assume "./MyScript.sh" is correct.

Comment: if you want to be sure about it, try writing: "QMAKE_POST_LINK = pwd".

Comment: @Galadrius Krunthar: the INCLUDEPATH variable will change the include paths sent to the compiler for looking up header files.  It won't change where the makefile looks for related files - you have to put the path in for those by hand.

Comment: I fixed the path and used just QMAKE_POST_LINK without target and then it finally worked.