# QMake: execute script after build

Tags: makefile, qmake

This is for setting up the application bundle of a MacOSX app. I have a script which copies a few files and does some other things. So I want to execute the script after the build (i.e. after the linking step). I want it to be executed just every time because it is not possible to specify its dependencies.

I know there is `QMAKE_POST_LINK` (e.g. described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300148/get-qmake-to-execute-shell-script-after-build-finished-on-mac) or [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2559)) but it runs only when the target does not exists, i.e. when linking needs to be done. However, I want the script to run every time, also when the target already exists.

There is also `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS` and `POST_TARGETDEPS` (e.g. described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946896/how-to-execute-shell-command-after-compile-finished-from-pro-in-qt)) but that forces a relink all the time but I actually only want the script to rerun and it runs the script before the linking. (Currently, that's what I'm using using anyway, because I don't see a better way. [Here](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/app/app.pro) is my QMake source.)

Answer (score 1):

There is related questions [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946896/how-to-execute-shell-command-after-compile-finished-from-pro-in-qt/) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864689/qmake-pre-build-step-before-any-compilation). I quote my answer for first of them:

> Another way to make things in given order is to use empty "super"
>   target:
>
> ```
> super.depends = target_pre first target_post
> QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += super
> ```
>
> Where `first` - is default qmake target, and `target_pre` and
>   `target_post` some custom targets. Now `make super` just do the thing.

EDIT: looks like in last versions of Qt build of dependencies is running in paralell so this solution wouldn't work.

Comment: I think there's a good idea here. Wouldn't it work to make `target_post` depend on `first`, etc, and make `super` depend on `target_post`?

Answer (score 0):

I've scratched my head about this for a few man-days over the past several months, and I haven't yet found a "pure" solution. However, FWIW, if you don't mind the hack of forcing relink every time, here's how to do that:

(This implementation of "post-build-events" is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881164/3225396) implementation of "pre-build-events".)

Caveats:

- Forces relink every time
- Works only for projects that have a linking step, so, not
  `TEMPLATE=aux` or `TEMPLATE=subdirs`.

  ```
  FORCELINK_CPP_FILE = force_link.cpp

  #This batch of statements causes the dummy file to be touched each build.
  forcelink.target = $$FORCELINK_CPP_FILE
  #FORCE is a nonexistent target, which will cause Make to always re-execute the recipe.
  forcelink.depends = FORCE
  forcelink.commands = touch $$FORCELINK_CPP_FILE
  QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += forcelink

  #This statement ensures that touching the above file at Make time will force relinking.
  SOURCES += $$FORCELINK_CPP_FILE

  #QMake will complain unless the file actually exists at QMake time,
  # too, so we make sure it does.
  #I used to touch this on QMake build_pass runs, too,
  # but it caused transient access-denied errors.
  # I guess the release and debug makefiles are generated in parallel.
  !build_pass : write_file($$FORCELINK_CPP_FILE)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

What I did (for using innosetup):
I Create a project with the TEMPLATE "aux" and define a new compiler :

```
TEMPLATE = aux
IS_INPUT = $$PWD/install.iss
IS_OUTPUT = $$PWD/installer.exe
is.name = "innosetup"
is.input = IS_INPUT
is.output = IS_OUTPUT
is.commands =  "C:/Program Files (x86)/Inno Setup 6/iscc.exe" ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += is
```

The most important thing is the line is.commands

Then, I create a project with the TEMPLATE "subdirs", add all my projects, and, at the end, put the new "aux" project.

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    ./project1/sources/project1.pro \
    ./project2/sources/project2.pro \
    ./project3/sources/project3.pro \
    ./installer/installer.pro

CONFIG += ordered
```

Dont forget to add "CONFIG += ordered "