# qmake touch function on windows

Tags: qt, qmake

The qmake manual documents a `touch` function to update the time stamp of a file, see: [touch(filename, reference_filename)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#touchfunction). It is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946896/how-to-execute-shell-command-after-compile-finished-from-pro-in-qt/5948236#5948236) to update the timestamp on a file, e.g.:

```
version.commands = touch $$version.target
```

Note: the qmake manual documents two parameters, e.g.:

```
version.commands = touch $$version.target $$version.depends
```

However, I can't get the `touch` function to work on Windows using either call. I suspect that `qmake` is simply calling the `linux` [touch](http://www.linfo.org/touch.html) command, since it works fine on Fedora 23.

A workaround is to create a `touch.cmd` command file on Windows, e.g.:

```
@COPY /B %1+,, %1
```

and use the following in the `.pro` file:

```
version.commands = $$system(touch $$version.target)
```

But I would prefer to use the qmake `touch` function...

What is the correct way to invoke it in a `.pro` file so that it works on Windows?

Comment: system(@COPY /B file.name "+,,") - worked fine for me

Comment: It worked for me too @oklas, but it's still not the elusive `qmake touch`. Roll on [bash on Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about)...

Answer (score 0):

In using qmake, it's critical to remember what things are happening on invocation of qmake and what's happening during the subsequent make/nmake call.

Anything that's specified after `version.commands =` is going to be executed when make gets invoked.

On the other hand, `touch()` is a qmake function that will get invoked when you run qmake.

Looking in the Qt source code dev branch as of today, there are just 4 uses of touch() within Qt itself, all in the `qtbase/mkspecs/features` directory, and none in the context of a `.commands` construct.